# how i can create hidden folder in unix-AIX Version 6.1

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, aix, files

I try this command `mkdir .done` but it does not work. How does one create a hidden folder?

Comment: Seriously, if you want help you're going to have to put minimal effort into writing a question that we can understand and help you with; including whatever error code you're getting, or what is/isn't happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the output of `alias ls`?  It sounds like the folder is being created but you expect it to be hidden when you do a `ls`.  Perhaps your `ls` is aliased to `ls -a`?

Comment: I've seen this behaviour whilst logged in as root. Switching user to another account and running 'ls' again will show the new directory as hidden.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax works just fine for me on AIX 5.3; why don't you tell us what error you got when you tried? Or, are you sure that you typed `ls -a` to verify that it was there afterwards? If you just typed `ls` it won't show because it's hidden.

Comment: it doesen't creat heddin folder when i write `ls` the result is .done normaly `mkdir .done` can not creat hidden folder

Comment: Please edit your response to fix the spelling and grammar; I have no idea what you're saying.